# Obtaining fitted values from second-order quantile regressions

Tags: r, prediction, polynomials, quantreg, quantile-regression

I'm sure this is easily resolvable, but I have a question regarding quantile regression.

Say I have a data frame which follows the trend of a second-order polynomial curve and I construct a quantile regression fitted through different parts of the data:

```
##Data preperation
set.seed(5)
d <- data.frame(x=seq(-5, 5, len=51))
d$y <- 50 - 0.3*d$x^2 + rnorm(nrow(d))

##Quantile regression
Taus <- c(0.1,0.5,0.9)
QUA<-rq(y ~ 1 + x + I(x^2), tau=Taus, data=d)
plot(y~x,data=d)
for (k in 1:length(Taus)){
 curve((QUA$coef[1,k])+(QUA$coef[2,k])*(x)+(QUA$coef[3,k])*(x^2),lwd=2,lty=1, add = TRUE)
}
```

I can obtain the maximum y value through the 'predict.rq' function and you can see this the following plot.

[image: Plot obtained from above code]

```
 ##Maximum prediction
 Pred_df<- as.data.frame(predict.rq(QUA))
 apply(Pred_df,2,max)
```

**So my question is how do I obtain the x-value which corresponds to the maximum y-value (i.e. the break in slope) for each quantile?**

Comment: I think some of this could be very easily done with **broom**, but I'm a little unclear on what value you think is wrong? 51.63 seems like a reasonable value for the peak of the 0.9 quantile, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The 51.63 is reasonable, but that's the maximum value in the dataset (irrespective of the quantile regression). The 48.88 from the 90th percentile I thought seemed quite low given where it appears on the graph.

Comment: Ok, but that's the mean, not the max? That's why I was confused.

Comment: Yes you're exactly right, that is a very basic typo on my part. I will edit this now and change it to address the second question. Thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package **broom** could be very useful here:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
augment(QUA) %>% 
  group_by(.tau) %>% 
  filter(.fitted == max(.fitted))
```